# jquery - Trigger an element based on a constructed ID?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In IE6, I'm using jQuery to trigger a click of another link on a page whose ID is derived from the ID of another field, plus some text, in this case text, but it doesn't work.

```
var targetElm = $(this).attr('id') + 'Search';
alert(targetElm);
$(targetElm).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you put a `#` before the value of `targetElm`; jquery won't match an id without it.